# Using Navigation Drawers to Navigate Between Activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My application contains 6 Activities. I added a Navigation Drawer to my toolbar in all of them in order to toggle between them. I understand that Navigation Drawers are better suited for Fragments and that this adds a lot more code as I'm creating this drawer in each activity but is this ok to do? The application functions fine, I'm just wondering if it's good programming practice? Thank you.

Comment: Its good. Just that UX wise, it doesn't bring more interaction within your app. Look at YouTube, Look at Facebook, Look at Google+ although the nav is still there, but they threw the Tab Bar there cause it's easy to interact with

Comment: have you created NavigationDrawer in all your activities ??

Comment: No, this is not fine!  Just use Fragments.  You can't use a NavigationDrawer with Activities, and while what you did works, it is very very wrong and will probably explode if you need to add just a little more complexity.  Work with the framework, don't try to fight against it!

Comment: Ok, I figured as much. I'm gonna re write a few things. Thank you.

Comment: Quick follow up if you have a sec. So I'm placing my Activities into Fragments instead and then using a Navigation Drawer to Toggle between them in a Frame Layout. My Activities are very "stand alone" meaning each Fragment is by itself and not interacting with other Fragments, for example a calendar that displays the date.This would look the same on every device. EVERY tutorial I see has multiple Fragments interacting with one another. My question is, from a design perspective, is it ok to use Fragments like I am where each one is "stand alone" or should I just use Activities instead?Thank you